# How to set completed status using javascript trigger in articulate storyline 2

Tags: javascript, articulate-storyline

I want to set completed status to lms on a specific slide, so i have to use javascript trigger in this case. My question is: what should be the javascript code to set completed status on lms when this trigger runs on that specific slide.

Thanks in adavance

Answer (score 1):

```
var player = GetPlayer();
player.SetVar("complete","complete");
player.SetVar("Incomplete","Incomplete");
```

Comment: Respected, the code you provided is to set storyline variables with a value. This code is not sending any completion status to moodle LMS.

Answer (score 0):

Completed or incomplete status of storyline can be sent to lms using javascript trigger on any slide by using following code.

For completed: SetStatus("completed");

For incomplete: SetStatus("incomplete");